# Eden mail php imap connection failure

Tags: php, ssl, gmail-imap, eden

I try to get the Gmail inbox emails using Eden mail PHP from my localhost (XAMPP Apache server). But it throws a fatal error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Eden\Mail\Exception: Problem connecting to
>   ssl://imap.gmail.com:993. Check server, port or ssl settings for your
>   email server. 
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\edenMail\vendor\eden\mail\src\Imap.php:357
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\edenMail\vendor\eden\mail\src\Imap.php(170): Eden\Core\Exception::i()
>
> 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\edenMail\vendor\eden\mail\src\Imap.php(357): Eden\Mail\Imap->connect()
>
> 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\edenMail\index.php(36): Eden\Mail\Imap->getMailboxes()
>
> 3 {main}
>
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\edenMail\vendor\eden\mail\src\Imap.php on line 357

I have used below code in Eden mail's index.php file with my own credentials.

```
$imap = eden('mail')->imap(
    'imap.gmail.com', 
    'myEmailId', 
    'myPassword', 
    993, 
    true);
```

In addition to that, I have enabled IMAP/POP3 and turned on less secure apps as well in my Gmail settings.

I have encountered this error only when I try to connect from my localhost (Windows-Xampp-Apache server). But there is no error if test code in my web server working in Linux environment.

Could anyone please help me to connect the google imap.gmail.com to retrieve inbox emails?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the instructions given in the below link and got the issue resolved. I am sharing it as if may help anyone with the same issue.

https://www.hesk.com/knowledgebase/?article=72

## Having problems getting Gmail to work with HESK? Try these settings.

**» Email sending**

To send emails using Gmail server enter these details:

```
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port: 587
SSL Protocol: OFF
TLS Protocol: ON
SMTP Username: (your Gmail username)
SMTP Password: (your Gmail password)
```

Also make sure your "From email address" in HESK settings is set to your Gmail email address!

Still no luck? Check with your host if they have port 587 blocked in firewall.

**» POP3 fetching**

To fetch mail from Gmail server enter these details:

```
POP3 Host: pop.gmail.com
POP3 Port: 995
TLS Protocol: ON
POP3 Username: (your Gmail username)
POP3 Password: (your Gmail password)
```

> Important: make 100% sure that "POP3 download" in your Gmail settings
>   is set to "Enable POP for mail that arrives from now on". If not,
>   Gmail will send all existing (even read) messages to HESK when it
>   first connects.

**» IMAP fetching**

To fetch mail using IMAP from Gmail server enter these details:

```
POP3 Host: imap.gmail.com
POP3 Port: 993
Encryption: SSL
POP3 Username: (your Gmail username)
POP3 Password: (your Gmail password)
```

**» Error messages**

> Connection timed out

Required ports are probably blocked on your server's firewall. Ask your host to configure the firewall to allow TCP connections on ports `587`, `995` and/or `993`.

Some hosting companies will not do that due to their policies. In that case you will need to, in order to integrate Gmail with HESK, find another host or try the HESK cloud.

> Permission denied

Try logging with your google account here to unlock it for application access.

Click the "Continue" button to Allow access to your Google account.

> Password error: [AUTH] Username and password not accepted. Too many
>   login failures

Your username and/or password is not correct, double-check them ad remember passwords are CaSe SeNSiTiVe!

> Password error: [AUTH] Web login required

[See this article](https://www.hesk.com/knowledgebase/?article=73)

> Error: 0 could not connect to the host "pop.gmail.com"

This could mean that:

required ports are blocked on your server's firewall. Ask your host to unblock TCP connections on ports 587, 995 and/or 993
- OR -

SSL certificate verification fails on your server. Try this:
download this file
save it somewhere to your server, for example to `C:\wamp\ssl\cacert.pem`
open your `php.ini` file
find the line

```
;openssl.cafile=
```

and change it to the location of the `cacert.pem` file while also removing the starting `;`

```
openssl.cafile=C:\wamp\ssl\cacert.pem
```

save and restart the server
test again